Changes on Stock Report
I am trying to see the initial quantity for each product. As well as the Good receipt number that brought up the initial quantity to the system.
Here is my query:
select t2."ItemCode" ,t2."ItemName",  t1."Whscode",t4."ItmsGrpNam", t3."U_Batch" as "Batch Number", t3."LotNumber" as "Lot Number" ,'S' as "Type", convert(nchar(8), t3."ExpDate", 112) as "ExpirationDate", sum(t1.Quantity) as "Quantity"
from osrq t1 
left join oitm t2 on t2."Itemcode" = t1."ItemCode"
Left join osrn t3 on t3."SysNumber" = t1."SysNumber" and t3."ItemCode" = t1."ItemCode"
left join oitb t4 on t4.ItmsGrpCod = t2.ItmsGrpCodwhere  t1.Quantity > 0 and t4."ItmsGrpNam" >= '[%0]' and t4."ItmsGrpNam" <= '[%1]'
group by t2."ItemCode", t2."ItemName", t1."Whscode", t4."ItmsGrpnam", t3."U_Batch", t3.LotNumber, t3."ExpDate"
union all 
select t1."ItemCode" as "Item Code", T0."ItemName", t3."WhsCode", t2."ItmsGrpNam", isnull(T0."DistNumber",' ') as "Batch Number", t0."LotNumber", 'B' as 'Type',
convert(nchar(8), t0."ExpDate", 112) as "ExpiryDate", t3."Quantity" as Quantity
from OBTN t0
left join OITM t1 on t1."ItemCode" = t0."ItemCode"
left join OITB t2 on t2."ItmsGrpCod" = t1."ItmsGrpCod"
left join obtq t3 on T3."MdAbsEntry" = t0."AbsEntry"
where t3."Quantity" > 0 and t2."ItmsGrpNam" >= '[%0]' and t2."ItmsGrpNam" <= '[%1]'
order by "ItemCode", "ItemName", t1."Whscode", t3.LotNumber

I tried adding the Good receipt table (OIGN) and its quantity but the thing is how do I link that with the original quantity. Say in a case whereby the product quantity was brought couple of times.
SELECT t2."ItemCode", t2."ItemName", t1."Whscode", t4."ItmsGrpNam", t5."DocEntry", t3."U_Batch" AS "Batch Number", t3."LotNumber" AS "Lot Number",'S' AS "Type", CONVERT(nchar(8), t3."ExpDate", 112) AS "ExpirationDate", SUM(t1.Quantity) AS "Quantity" 
FROM osrq t1
LEFT JOIN oitm t2 ON t2."ItemCode" = t1."ItemCode" 
LEFT JOIN osrn t3 ON t3."SysNumber" = t1."SysNumber" AND t3."ItemCode" = t1."ItemCode" 
LEFT JOIN oitb t4 ON t4."ItmsGrpCod" = t2."ItmsGrpCod"
LEFT JOIN IGN1 t5 ON t5."ItemCode" = t1."ItemCode"
WHERE t1.Quantity > 0
GROUP BY t2."ItemCode", t2."ItemName", t1."Whscode", t4."ItmsGrpNam", t3."U_Batch", t3."LotNumber", t3."ExpDate"
ORDER BY t2."ItemCode", t3."U_Batch";


Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results

FYI: Its best practice (and far more useful to anyone reading your SQL), to use meaningful aliases for your tables.

Do you have a date in the table you can order by ?  Earliest date will give first record.  Is the first record the initial quantity?

yes I can use the docdate which is the posting date of the transaction

please format your sql code to make it more readable

This question would really be better understood if you would show us some sample data and expected outcome

I tried to create a table and sample data based on whatever info available in your question and ran 2nd query in the question. Then I modified join condition and group by. db-fiddle

last join condition in 2nd query to add BaseType, BaseLine and DocEntry

LEFT JOIN
    ign1 t5 ON t5."ItemCode" = t1."ItemCode" AND t5."BaseType" = '67' AND t5."BaseEntry" = t1."DocEntry" AND t5."BaseLine" = t1."LineNum"


update group by statement to include DocEntry

    t2."ItemCode", t2."ItemName", t1."Whscode", t4."ItmsGrpNam", t5."DocEntry", t3."U_Batch", t3."LotNumber", t3."ExpDate"

Please let me know in case I failed to understand your question in first place.
